# Does there exist a k such that the kth prime is balanced in order k-1?

Tags: prime-numbers

[A balanced prime of order n is a prime number that is equal to the arithmetic mean of the nearest n primes above and below.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_prime)

For example, 5 is a balanced prime in order 1 because it is the average of the prime before it (3) and the prime after it (7).

There is a highest order a prime could be balanced in: the number of primes that are less than it. The question of whether 5, the 3rd prime, is balanced in order 3 is undefined. So the kth prime could be said to be maximally balanced if it's balanced in order k-1; i.e. if you take all the primes less than a prime p, and that many primes greater than it, and average them, you get p again.

The first 500 primes are each less than the average of the primes surrounding them, and the difference tends to increase, but it doesn't *strictly* increase. So my guess would be that no maximally balanced prime exists, but I doubt there's a quick proof. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p_k$ is $(k-1)$-balanced ($k>1$) then
$$p_k=\frac{p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_{k-1}+p_{k+1}+\ldots+p_{2k-1}}{2(k-1)}. $$
Since $p_1=2$, the numerator is the sum of $2k-3$ odd numbers and $2$, hence odd. Dividing by an even denominator cannot produce an integer.

Comment: Very nice! That means the highest possible order the kth prime can be balanced in is k-2, and there is at least one such prime, 5.

Answer (score 1):

Heuristically, the $(n+1)$th prime is $\sim n\log n$. The sum of the first $2n+1$ primes is $\sim S_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(2n+1)^2\log(2n+1)$. We want $(S_{2n+1}-n\log n)\frac{1}{2n} \sim n\log n$. Well, this is true, which suggests (in the weakest possible sense) that there may be infinitely many maximally balanced primes. There are better estimates for the $n$th prime, or the sum of the first $n$ primes, maybe those will give a different result - I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a simple reason why it can never happen. Prime $p_k$ is maximally balanced if
$$ p_k = (\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k-1}p_i)/2(k-1) $$
In this sum, you have one even number $p_1 = 2$ and $(k-2)+(k-1)=2k-3$ odd numbers. This means that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k-1} \equiv 2k-3 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$
which means that the sum will never be divisible by an even number.